# Connecting to remote MySQL server without specifying schema

Tags: mysql

When I connect to my Remote HostGator MySQL server without specifying a database schema, it takes about 30 seconds to connect.  If I specify a database schema when connecting, it takes only 1 second.  In both cases, subsequent queries work fine and fast.

Doing the same with my localhost MySQL server connects fast regardless.

Does anyone know why the connection is slow when you don't specify a database schema during connect?

Unfortunately, I don't have access to the mysql config.ini file on my shared Hostgator server.

Answer (score 0):

When you are connecting the Mysql server remotely without specifying the database schema, your HostGator MySQL server takes time to lookup for all users / passwords, grants to access resources to all databases and host details etc.

But, when you specifically mentioning the database, it just checks all these things for a single database and works fast.

In case of local system, it does all these things within the milliseconds as there in no any connection with a remote server, no DNS lookup, no bandwidth issue etc. hence it is faster.

Comment: Seems plausible.  I feared this might be the case.  Still, it seems surprisingly slow even if there are many databases on the server.  I wonder how many databases does it take to cause a slow connection such as this.

Comment: there will be the several parameters causing the slow connection issue, server region, server h/w, memory, your bandwidth, also the number of databases which you are saying, actually the time required will be in the directly proportion of number of databases, will not cause to the particular database count  I think.

Comment: you could do an experiment with the number of databases and make the conclusion

Comment: I thought the same... I may try an experiment.  Even a noticable difference to connection time could be extrapolated and might be sufficient to draw a more certain conclusion.  If so... then this means the only solution is to pay for a dedicated server :)

Comment: I tried adding hundreds of databases to my localhost mysql server, but that did not cause a slow connection.  Perhaps it has something to do with multiple users and differing permissions?